Add data to event in open62541
I want to add some data to my event on a opcua server using open62541
What worked so far:
I added a new Event to BaseEventType.
I can send severity and time from my server to OpcUaExpert
My Issue :
I want to add a property for example "TemperatureEvent" to my event type "CustomEvent".
OpcUaExpert shows this property in the address space  Root - Types - EventTypes but I cannot see the value of the temperature in the eventView.
Pictures OpcUA Expert:

MyServerCode:
addObjectTypeNode and addVariableNode to my Event "CustomEvent"
    UA_ObjectTypeAttributes attr = UA_ObjectTypeAttributes_default;
    attr.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "CustomEvent");
    attr.description = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "Event for ...");
    UA_Server_addObjectTypeNode(server, UA_NODEID_NULL, UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_BASEEVENTTYPE),
                                UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_HASSUBTYPE),
                                UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(NamespaceIndex, "CustomEvent"), attr, NULL, &eventType);

    // Add Temperature field to the event type
    UA_VariableAttributes temperatureAttr = UA_VariableAttributes_default;
    temperatureAttr.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "TemperatureEvent");
    temperatureAttr.dataType = UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_DOUBLE].typeId;
    UA_NodeId temperatureAttrId;
    UA_Server_addVariableNode(server, UA_NODEID_NULL, eventType, UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_HASPROPERTY),
                              UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(NamespaceIndex, "TemperatureEvent"),
                              UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_PROPERTYTYPE), temperatureAttr, NULL, NULL);


    std::thread threadObjTriggerEvent(threadTriggerEvent, server);

Trigger the event in a thread (executed every x seconds)
        UA_NodeId eventNodeId;
        UA_StatusCode retval = UA_Server_createEvent(server, eventType, &eventNodeId);

        // informations for ua expert
        UA_DateTime eventTime = UA_DateTime_now();
        UA_Server_writeObjectProperty_scalar(server, eventNodeId, UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(0, "Time"), &eventTime,
                                             &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_DATETIME]);

        UA_UInt16 eventSeverity = 100;
        UA_Server_writeObjectProperty_scalar(server, eventNodeId, UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(0, "Severity"), &eventSeverity,
                                             &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_UINT16]);

        UA_LocalizedText eventMessage = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "An event has been generated.");
        UA_Server_writeObjectProperty_scalar(server, eventNodeId, UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(0, "Message"), &eventMessage,
                                             &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_LOCALIZEDTEXT]);

        // Event data: Temperature
        UA_Double temperature = 23.5;// Example temperature value
        UA_Server_writeObjectProperty_scalar(server, eventNodeId, UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(2, "TemperatureEvent"), &temperature,
                                             &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_DOUBLE]);

        // trigger this event
        retval = UA_Server_triggerEvent(server, eventNodeId, UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_SERVER), NULL, UA_TRUE);      

Maybe someone knows what I am doing wrong, thanks !

I'm new to open62541, so this is a noob answer, but maybe it helps:
I had the same problem and stumbled upon your question while looking for an answer. So I will tell you what I found:
I noticed that the propertys of the BaseEventType all have the "HasModellingRule" Reference ("Optional" or "Mandatory"), but my custom added property of my derived event did not have that. So I added the "HasModellingRule" "Mandatory" Reference to it and now it works. You can see the custom property in the Details view of an Event.
Applied to the first code block you posted it would look like this
UA_NodeId eventType;

UA_ObjectTypeAttributes attr = UA_ObjectTypeAttributes_default;
attr.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "CustomEvent");
attr.description = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "Event for ...");

UA_Server_addObjectTypeNode(server, UA_NODEID_NULL, UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_BASEEVENTTYPE), UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_HASSUBTYPE), UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(NamespaceIndex, "CustomEvent"), attr, NULL, &eventType);

// Add Temperature field to the event type
UA_VariableAttributes temperatureAttr = UA_VariableAttributes_default;
temperatureAttr.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "TemperatureEvent");
temperatureAttr.dataType = UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_DOUBLE].typeId;

UA_NodeId temperatureAttrId;

UA_Server_addVariableNode(server, UA_NODEID_NULL, eventType, UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_HASPROPERTY), UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(NamespaceIndex, "TemperatureEvent"), UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_PROPERTYTYPE), temperatureAttr, NULL, &temperatureAttrId);

UA_Server_addReference(server, temperatureAttrId, UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_HASMODELLINGRULE), UA_EXPANDEDNODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_MODELLINGRULE_MANDATORY), true);

